# Javascript - Toggle Multiple Classes onclick

Tags: javascript

I am trying to toggle multiple classes **onclick** using vanilla Javascript. What i am trying to do is when a btn is clicked two classes to toggle with another two classes. I have 5 classes in total which are: **.menu_btn** , **.main_nav**, **.btn_active**, **.container**, **.container_active**. When i press the .**menu_btn** i would like the classes **.main_nav** to toggle with **.btn_active** and at the same time i would like to have the **.container** to toggle with **.container_active**. The class **.container** is the only one that has 5 elements of that class, the others are single. I have done this using jQuery but i would like to know the way using vanilla Javascript. Hopefully someone can help.

One thing to point out is when i **console.log** the **.btn_active** and **.container_active** i get back [ ] an empty array. Those 2 css classes are not assigned to any element of my project. They are existing only in the css and their purpose is for toggle.

Thanks

jQuery Code:

```
$(function(){

   $(".menu_btn").on("click", function(){

       $(".main_nav").toggleClass("btn_active");
       $(".container").toggleClass("container_active");

   }); 

});
```

Vanilla Javascript Code:

```
var menuBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("menu_btn");
var mainNav = document.getElementsByClassName("main_nav");
var btnActive = document.getElementsByClassName("btn_active");
var container = document.getElementsByClassName("container");
var containerActive = document.getElementsByClassName("container_active");

menuBtn.onclick = function(){

    mainNav.classList.toggle(btnActive);
    for ( index = 0; index <= container.lenght -1; index++ ){
        container[index].classList.toggle(containerActive);
    }

};
```

Comment: Replace `container[index].classList.toggle(containerActive);` with `container[index].classList.toggle('containerActive');`

Comment: Not working @gurvinder372. Even the first class mainNav does not toggle with btnActive. Dont know what is wrong

Comment: Sorry I meant `'container_Active'` not `'containerActive'`

Comment: still nothing is working

Comment: Can you create a fiddle and share the same?

Comment: I have tried to create it but its not the same as my project because i have some external css files included and some other JS files. Basically i have 1 btn and when is clicked i would like to toggle 2 classes with another 2 classes at the same same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your script and created a fiddle so you see how it works: https://jsfiddle.net/eyrpdsc2/

The toggle accepts a string as a parameter, not a Node. So you need to pass 'btn_active' instead of btnActive. Also keep in mind that querySelectorAll returns a NodeList (not an array) so you cannot use forEach.

```
var menuBtn = document.querySelectorAll(".menu_btn");
var mainNav = document.querySelectorAll(".main_nav");
var container = document.querySelectorAll(".container");

for (var i = 0; i < menuBtn.length; ++i) {
    menuBtn[i].addEventListener('click', toggleClasses);
}

function toggleClasses() {
        var i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < mainNav.length; ++i) {
        mainNav[i].classList.toggle('btn_active');
    }
    for (i = 0; i < container.length; ++i) {
        container[i].classList.toggle('container_active');
    }
}
```